# Surface Pro 4 won't wake up on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: suspend, surface, 18.04

I use Ubuntu 18.04 on my Surface Pro 4. I have a problem with the sleep mode. When my Surface Pro goes to sleep, I can't wake it up with the keyboard, mouse or power button. I need to use hard shutdown. I think the device is waking up but the screen is staying black.

Comment: This answer contains a correct answer to another question, thus **voting to reopen1  :-)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrade the kernel to v4.16 With UKUU.

**You should install Ubuntu Kernel Upgrade Utility (UKUU).**

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

**Run UKUU with this command:**

```
sudo ukuu-gtk
```

In the UKUU GUI select Kernel 4.16 and install it. When the process finishes, you have to reboot.

**Try it!**

If after waking up, your Wifi is broken, you may tell to your system that, we want to explicitly unload on suspend and reload on the resume.

**Create new dir /etc/pm/config.d**

```
sudo mkdir /etc/pm/config.d
```

**Create a new file in this dir**

```
sudo touch config
```

**Edit this file**

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

**Add one line:**

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi"
```

Save, close and reboot.

Comment: I don't care if this question is off topic, and that saying "thanks!" is considered bad form. This question, and the answer to it are correct and worked for me and my Surface Pro 3. Now if only the touchpad was a bit less mental.